Java compile process throws error before OpenApi generates code
I'm building a REST:API with Spring Boot and I'm using the OpenAPI plugin to generate my stubs and DTO's (Ao's).
I already used the OpenAPI plugin in another project which worked perfectly fine. But now I'm running in this unknown problem, that the service can't find the the Ao Class. Due to this fact the project cannot build because the service relies on those classes that are created by the plugin.
So I get this error message:
error: package ao does not exist, import ao.ProductAo;
Strangely enough if I leave the service open, immediately after my failed compileJava process, the error disappears and can find it.
I declared in my build.gradle that the my compileJava depends on the openApiGenerate task like this:
compileJava.dependsOn tasks.openApiGenerate
I added the OpenAPI plugin and dependency to my project as followed:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "7.5.0"
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    implementation 'org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.6'
...

And configured the OpenAPI codegen like this:
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("spring")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/openApiResources/openapi.yaml")
    outputDir.set(rootProject.layout.buildDirectory.get().toString() + "/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main/openapi")
    apiPackage.set("api")
    modelPackage.set("ao")
    configOptions.set([dateLibrary   : "java8",
                       useSpringBoot3: "true",
                       interfaceOnly : "true"
    ])
}

The first error is thrown in my controller. Maybe this snippet can help :
...

import ao.ProductAo;

import java.util.List;

@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

    private final ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/{articleNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<ProductAo> getProduct(@PathVariable Long articleNumber){
        var product = this.productService.findByArtNumber(articleNumber);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(product,HttpStatus.OK);
}
...

I tried moving around the: compileJava.dependsOn tasks.openApiGenerate and the plugin configuration in the hope that the position could have any impact. This didn't solve the problem.
Unfortunately I'm clueless how I could solve this problem. May there someone who could help me out?

Moving the output directory to another under build and set this to sourceset solved my problem.
